# Make Units Comparable on Axes of Two Plots

Tags: graphics

I have two graphs and I want to have the ratio of the units on the horizontal and vertical axes be the same. I do not want to use `AspectRatio->Automatic` because the vertical dimension would be too small. Here is some sample code:

```
egl = {Line[{
     {0, .1}, {2, .3}}],
   Line[{
     {1.5, -.23}, {1.5, .7}}]};
g1 = Graphics[
   egl,
   Axes -> True,
   AspectRatio -> .5,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, .25}}]
g2 = Graphics[
   egl,
   Axes -> True,
   AspectRatio -> 1.5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `PlotRange` as well. In your first example you made at this point a mistake.

```
g1 = Graphics[egl, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.25/2, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, .25}}]
```

More general:

```
pRange = {{0, 2}, {0, .25}}
g1e = Graphics[egl, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/Divide @@ Flatten[Differences /@ pRange], PlotRange -> pRange]
```

The second example should be like that:

```
g2 = Graphics[egl, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

When you use `AspectRatio -> 1` then the intervalls have to be equal. Means:

```
Differences@{0,2} == Differences@{-1,1}
(* True *)
```

Why do you use `Show`?

Comment: Many thanks, I accepted the answer. I use show because I have been using Mathematica since version 2.0. I'll try to drop it.